# Godot: Mesh Editing

Tags: godot

Is there any way to contact the surfaces of a given mesh in Godot with script? I would like to simulate a growing grass surface, and want to change the texture of each surface of the mesh to a grass one as it grows over those surfaces. Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to contact the surfaces of a given mesh in Godot with script?

I'm not sure what you mean by contact.

Given the title (Godot: Mesh Editing), you could be interested in procedural geometry, see the documentation ([4.x](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/tutorials/3d/procedural_geometry/index.html), [3.x](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/3d/procedural_geometry/index.html)).

Just in case, I'll also point you to [Using Decals](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/tutorials/3d/using_decals.html) (This is a Godot 4 feature).

---

> I would like to simulate a growing grass surface

If you want to create a mesh that changes over time (grow), probably the tools of choice is [`ImmediateMesh` in 4.x](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/classes/class_immediatemesh.html#class-immediatemesh)/[`ImmediateGeometry` in 3.x](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_immediategeometry.html#class-immediategeometry).

However, if you make the grass flat, you might also simulate grass growing by animating the textures plus alpha scissors.

---

> and want to change the texture of each surface of the mesh to a grass one as it grows over those surfaces

If you need to read an existing mesh, use `MeshDataTool` ([4.x](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/tutorials/3d/procedural_geometry/meshdatatool.html)/[3.x](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_meshdatatool.html#class-meshdatatool)).

---

> Is there any good way to do this?

Honestly, I would suggest against procedural geometry for grass. Instead, consider using particles ([`GPUParticles3D` in 4.x](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/classes/class_gpuparticles3d.html)/[`Particles` in 3.x](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_particles.html#class-particles)).

Alternatively, you could consider to use a `Multimesh` ([4.x](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/classes/class_multimesh.html)/[3.x](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_multimesh.html)).